Is there a way around using getDirectoryListing() in AS3 for large dirs?
I have an AIR app that imports and parses file data. It works fine when dirs contain around 5000 files, but I have users that have dirs with 300,000-600,000 files in them, and it hangs the UI.
My file parsing code works very efficiently - I have timers and enter frame chunking systems in place to update the UI once the dir has been read, but the initial dir.getDirectoryListing() read hangs the app. I've isolated the hang to
var f1:Array = d1.getDirectoryListing();

Everything else around this line works blistering fast, even parsing 600,000 records.
I could use getDirectoryListingAsync() and display a "Reading your directory. Please wait..." pop up with an animation, but getting the dir listing takes multiple minutes on larger dirs and makes it look like the app has hung.
I've played with having Python handle the file read and sending my AIR app json to parse, but then realised that I would need the end user to install python i.e. not gonna happen.
I've played with trying to select a limited amount of files and multiple dir reads, but they still rely on getDirectoryListing, which introduces the hang.
What are other approaches that I could take please?
Thank you

Have you thought about running dir (https://www.lifewire.com/dir-command-4050018) command via NativeProcess (https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html) with output redirected to a local file > directory.txt to read that file afterwards?

Oh, I read up a bit and you don't even need a file for that, you can just read stdout directly.

I'll look at this today Organis. I learned that I can bundle Python with the Python .exe so that the end user doesn't have to install Python - I'm about 1/2 way through implementing it. Very exciting to hear that I can read stdout directly - I'll check that out too! NativeProcess was hard to get working - I've not been able to create an AIR file with it - had to create a .exe file instead. Had AIR errors during publishing if I had extendedDesktop set as the only profile - it wanted desktop too, but then NativeProcess refused to work. Just means I know also need to compile on a Mac. Thank you!

As a side note, have you tried File.getDirectoryListingAsync()? If your exact problem is not the reading duration itself but the un-responsive UI, then it is what you might be looking for.

Thank you Organis. I thought about trying it but the duration was as much a concern as the hanging. I also took a look at the dir command link you posted, but I've stuck with Python as I wanted a Windows and Mac solution. I've almost finished the integration and can't believe how fast it is now. I tested it on a dir of a million test mp3s, which would have taken an afternoon (not kidding) to import and parse on my current production code, and it does it in under 20 seconds now with the python and AS3 tweaks
